# KendoUI upload not working in IE9

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendoui upload control (Async mode) in my asp.net application.I am able to successfully upload file using Google chrome,Firefox and IE10 but in IE9 ,upload event fires and file uploads successfully but success event of kendo upload does not fire and it always goes to error event.

kendo upload make ajax call to asp.net apiController where I have written sub which does not return anything.

I get response with 204 code which shows no content.I tried to return json as response but still in that case success event of kendoui upload does not fire.

below are the urls of screenshots my response header and body.

http://screencast.com/t/0KQ0KF9mC
http://screencast.com/t/tCAC1JJ6No59

Please help me.

Regards

Imran

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, so you may have solved this already, but I had the same problem and the solution was simple:

Set the response header content-type to `'text/html'`